# Problem with linking Boost 1.79 libs, builded with MinGW GCC, with CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, boost, cmake

I'm using Boost 1.79 and Windows 10. For building Boost libs I use TDM MinGW. After trying to build my test program with CMake, I get next error:

```
CMake Error at D:/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: log thread) (found suitable version
  "1.79.0", minimum required is "1.79")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  D:/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  D:/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2376 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
#set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "D:/TDM-MinGW/bin/gcc.exe")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "D:/TDM-MinGW/bin/g++.exe")
set(Boost_DEBUG=ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)

project (testlib)

find_package(Boost 1.79 COMPONENTS log thread REQUIRED)

IF(Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
    MESSAGE("Boost information")
    MESSAGE("Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    MESSAGE("Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
    MESSAGE("Boost_Version: ${Boost_VERSION}")
    MESSAGE("Boost Libraries: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
ENDIF()

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
add_executable(testlib src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(testlib PUBLIC  ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

Boost libs were compiled by following command:

```
./b2 --build-type=complete -j 8 variant=debug address-model=64 link=static toolset=gcc install
```

Comment: Did you check to see if the libraries for the 2 components exits in the install folder?

Comment: @drescherjm, Yes, all libraries are exists

Comment: Instead of `set(Boost_DEBUG=ON)` you probably want `set(Boost_DEBUG ON)` (with a space replacing the equal sign).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I solved my problem, I just set `Boost_COMPILER` and `Boost_ARCHITECTURE` variables and everything works fine

Comment: Please self-answer adding additional log info to the question if it is available after making the change that @Tsyvarev mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solve my problem by setting `Boost_DEBUG` to `ON`. After analyzing debug info it became clear that the problem was two empty variables: `Boost_COMPILER` and `Boost_ARCHITECTURE`. And to solve the problem i just set these variables by looking at the full filename, for example:

We have filename `libboost_log-clang14-mt-x32-1_79.lib`, and we need this parts: `-clang14` and `-x32`. You should look at this parts at your filename and set this parts as CMake variables:

`Boost_ARCHITECTURE` = `-x32`

`Boost_COMPILER` = `-clang14`